# In a fragment if I press back button go to SettingsActivity.class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio-3.0

I have a `activity_settings.xml` file like below in this file I have 3 text views if I click one it will take me to a fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.crowderia.chat.SettingsActivity"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_added_me"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Added Me" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_add_friends"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Friends" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_my_friends"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Friends" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My SettingsActivity.class like below

onclick event for each text view

```
tv_added_me.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setFragment(new AddedMeFragment());
            }
        });
```

set fragment method

```
public void setFragment(Fragment f) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.settings_fragment, f);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

If I click each text view it will take me to each fragment but after I click back its not going to go to Settings Activity how can I make this work

> Please help me Im new to these stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove all the fragments from `FragmentManager` on the click of back button.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
for (Fragment f : fm.getFragments()) {
    fm.beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
}
```

Comment: where should i put this one can u explain a little please

Comment: in @override onBackPressed() method.

Comment: If you are willing to perform on device back button, you shall write into `onBackPressed()`. If you are using toolbar with back arrow, you should write in the click of back arrow.

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for (Fragment f : fm.getFragments()) {
            fm.beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
        }
    } something like this right

Comment: Remove `super.onBackPressed()` because it will close your `activity`